# Decrease Decimals in Fourth Column In a Text File

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a text file where the fourth column contains numbers with many decimal places. I need to reduce the places to 0.1 decimal place.

Data:

```
2015041416 KBOS TMP2M 62.034
2015041417 KBOS TMP2M 65.0826
2015041418 KBOS TMP2M 66.7278
2015041419 KBOS TMP2M 67.5033
2015041420 KBOS TMP2M 67.1731
2015041421 KBOS TMP2M 65.9252
2015041422 KBOS TMP2M 62.7644
2015041423 KBOS TMP2M 60.8136
2015041500 KBOS TMP2M 56.167
2015041501 KBOS TMP2M 55.7116
2015041502 KBOS TMP2M 51.8512
2015041503 KBOS TMP2M 51.6005
2015041504 KBOS TMP2M 50.1643
2015041505 KBOS TMP2M 49.2167
2015041506 KBOS TMP2M 48.273
2015041507 KBOS TMP2M 46.6407
```

Comment: When "reduced" does `62.7644` become `62.7` or `62.8`? In other words are you looking to truncate or round up or round down or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %s %.1f\n",$1, $2, $3, $4}' file > file2
```

Output to file2:

```
2015041416 KBOS TMP2M 62.0
2015041417 KBOS TMP2M 65.1
2015041418 KBOS TMP2M 66.7
2015041419 KBOS TMP2M 67.5
2015041420 KBOS TMP2M 67.2
2015041421 KBOS TMP2M 65.9
2015041422 KBOS TMP2M 62.8
2015041423 KBOS TMP2M 60.8
2015041500 KBOS TMP2M 56.2
2015041501 KBOS TMP2M 55.7
2015041502 KBOS TMP2M 51.9
2015041503 KBOS TMP2M 51.6
2015041504 KBOS TMP2M 50.2
2015041505 KBOS TMP2M 49.2
2015041506 KBOS TMP2M 48.3
2015041507 KBOS TMP2M 46.6
```

---

Same output with bash and without awk:

```
printf "%s %s %s %.1f\n" $(< file) > file2
```

Comment: Precisely. I need to round the large number of decimals down to the tenths place (ex. 0.1).

Comment: @AaronPerry you just said you need to round down but this solution rounds up. Think about what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Awk with rounding:

```
awk '{printf("%d %s %s %.1f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4) } ' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you want:

```
$ awk '{$NF=sprintf("%.1f",$NF)}1' file
2015041416 KBOS TMP2M 62.0
2015041417 KBOS TMP2M 65.1
2015041418 KBOS TMP2M 66.7
2015041419 KBOS TMP2M 67.5
2015041420 KBOS TMP2M 67.2
2015041421 KBOS TMP2M 65.9
2015041422 KBOS TMP2M 62.8
2015041423 KBOS TMP2M 60.8
2015041500 KBOS TMP2M 56.2
2015041501 KBOS TMP2M 55.7
2015041502 KBOS TMP2M 51.9
2015041503 KBOS TMP2M 51.6
2015041504 KBOS TMP2M 50.2
2015041505 KBOS TMP2M 49.2
2015041506 KBOS TMP2M 48.3
2015041507 KBOS TMP2M 46.6
```

It will work regardless of how many fields you have in the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to cut decimals without rounding you can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\)[0-9]*$/\1/' input
```

It searches for one or more numbers followed by a dot and one additional number captured in a capturing group. the following optional numbers until the end of the line get thrown away.

If you need to round, `sed` can't do this since it does not support math calculations at all. In this case I would suggest to use `awk` like other answers suggested.